# SQL Server Management Studio Change User Server Roles to sysadmin?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, role

On my local machine I have SSMS (SQL Server 2008 R2).

For user `xxxx` Server Roles are only `public`.

When I try to change it to `sysadmin` it throws the error:

> User does not have permission to perform this action. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>   Error Code 15247

1. Server type (local)/SQLExpress
2. Authentication: Windows Authentication
3. User: ComputerName\username (disabled)
4. Password: none (disabled)

How can I do this?

The user I am connecting with server role is: `public`, but Windows Admin user.

The instance is configured for mixed mode authentication, but I don't remember the password for `sa`. I can't change the password because I am not `sysadmin`.

Is there any way I can create a `sysadmin` user account or make my account `sysadmin` and get full control of my SSMS?

Answer (score 2):

You've explained that you don't have the SA password and you're not an administrator. In that case, you're going to have to hack your way around it.

See [Think Your Windows Administrators Don’t Have Access to SQL Server 2008 by Default? Think Again.](https://www.0xsql.com/2011/07/10/think-your-windows-administrators-dont-have-access-to-sql-server-2008-by-default-think-again/) by Argenis Fernandez.

That post explains how to impersonate the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` login using `PsExec` (or creating a Windows Scheduled Task running under the `SYSTEM` account) to create a new login for yourself. Then, you can log in via that new login, and grant your Windows account SA permissions.